# Why don't my default Jekyll links work on my live site? Only locally?

Tags: markdown, jekyll

I've used Jekyll for lots of projects and never had this issue.

Basically, my site works fine locally for a serve, but if I build and upload to mydomain.com suddenly none of the basic page links (which all go to "mydomain.com/page") don't work. They work if I manually make them "mydomain.com/page.html" but not as they are normally with just "mydomain.com/page"

My config and setup is extremely simple:

```
baseurl: ""
url: "mydomain.com"

header_pages:
  - index.md
  - dates.md
```

I am using the shell theme: https://tareqdandachi.github.io/jekyll-shell-theme/

Two pages: index.md and dates.md, both setup as:

```
---
layout: home
permalink: /
permalink_name: /home
title: Home
---
```

and

```
---
layout: page
permalink: /dates
permalink_name: /dates
title: Dates
---
```

But if I click the link in the nav bar to dates, I just get a default 'Not found' error (not the 404 error configured in Jekyll).

So it's like none of the '/page' type links are working? But they work if it's 'page.html'

What's going on? Is it something obvious? Something configured wrong on my server maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `jekyll serve` command starts a web server with fairly relaxed rules to support a wide range of potential production setups. These rules likely do not match your production web server. The solution is to find a scheme that works on both.

As an example, `jekyll serve` serves `/about.html` at (from memory):

- `/about.html`
- `/about`
- `/about/`
- `/about/index.html`

I prefer using trailing slashes on your permalinks, as it's supported by default almost everywhere. This means Jekyll is outputting the file to `/about/index.html`, but you can access it with `/about/`.

You can definitely get extensionless URLs working (and it's pretty common these days), usually you'd have to set up the web server so it knows to serve `/about.html` when `/about` is requested. You might also want to redirect `/about/` back to `/about` or vice versa - at this point it's a bit subjective.

Comment: Thank you! Adding a trailing slash to my permalink (i.e. "/dates/") worked just fine.